# Returning arraylist error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've been trying to create a class which determines if a set of integers within an arraylist is a subset of another arraylist.

However, I receive an "error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to int" whenever I try to compile and it appears that "return members" is causing it.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with "return members"? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Define the Set class

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Set {

    private ArrayList<Integer> members;

    public Set()
    {
        members = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public int getMembers()
    {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers()
    {
        this.members = members;
    }

    // toString() method
    public String toString() 
    {
        return "Set A is a subset of set B.";
    }

    // Return true if 'this' is a subset of 'set', 
    // otherwise return false.
    public boolean isSubset(Set set) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.members.size(); i++)
            if(!members.contains(this.members.get(i)))
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `if(!members.contains(this.members.get(i)))` really what you want? It will never be true. Also you should use brackets around your loops.

Comment: I'm trying to get the program to return false if the number is not contained in the second subset. Why will it never be true?

Comment: Because you are working on the same variable. You retrieve an element of `members` and check if `members` contains this element. Obviously it does otherwise you would not be able to get the element. Also the parameter `set` is not used. I think `if(!set.contains(members.get(i)))` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is your issue:

```
public int getMembers()
{
    return members;
}
```

Wrong return type, change it to:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getMembers()
{
    return members;
}
```

Also your setMembers() does not do anything, set's itself to itself. It should be changed to:

```
public void setMembers(ArrayList<Integer> newMembers)
{
    this.members = newMembers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I realized it was a mutator!

Answer (score 0):

you are making mistake in first place.change return type in `getMenbers()`. you are returning an Object type and you specified it to return an int(primitive).
a typical method can only return the specified type. hope it helps